# How to display adjacent tabs in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Here is a sample from [duolingo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duolingo):

[image: Swiping tabs of different sections]

I want to implement a similar feature. I can use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to make swiping tabs. What I can't seem to figure out is how to display the adjacent tabs (part of it) alongside the current tab, which is in the center.

I initially thought of implementing this using horizontal [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html), but I don't know how to make the snapping effect. And it also seemed more reasonable to use something which already provides you with swiping and snapping than try to implement your own.

Using ViewPager also let's me use fragments and memory management is also effective for cases of more than a few tabs.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Take a `FrameLayout` if first and then use `ViewPager` as a child widget of that layout.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi I had already considered this, but it doesn't displays the adjacent tabs. Here is what I tried https://github.com/ishanatmuz/ReminderTest/tree/81e7826c15d6caa43bd616b90c78b5c964dff4aa  In it I have set the size of the viewPager to be 300 X 300 while I set the size of the fragments to be 200 X 200, but still the fragments take up the whole space of the viewpager, and no adjacent tabs are displayed.